# Parse Error ViewMasterPage<TModel>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I am trying to implement a strongly typed master page and using this page as an example:

[How to create a strongly typed master page using a base controller in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768236/how-to-create-a-strongly-typed-master-page-using-a-base-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

I have the following declaration in my masterpage:

`<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<InsTech.ForeSight.Web.Mvc.ModelBase>" %>`

When I try to run I get:
Parser Error Message: Could not load type `'System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<InsTech.ForeSight.Web.Mvc.ModelBase>'`

I am not really sure why it can't find the type.  When I use the ViewMasterPage class everything is okay, but when I try to use the generic version it bombs.

Any Suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is InsTech.ForeSight.Web.Mvc.ModelBase in another assembly? if so, is it referenced?

Is InsTech.ForeSight.Web.Mvc.ModelBase abstract?

Comment: New Day, Fresh Mind, Saw my stupid error.  Thanks for your help

Comment: I guess I should have explained my problem in case anyone finds this in the future.  Since I was adding MVC to an existing web form project, I didn't realize that the default MVC template had a web.config in the views folder.  This web.config defines some default values for the pages configuration section that MVC will need.

Comment: @Whoiskb what exactly did you need to add? I'm facing the same problem, inheriting from ViewMasterPage works, but not ViewMasterPage<T>. Added the Views\web.config from a MVC project.

Comment: @Whoiskb, I am facing the same issue. Can you pls. suggest what did you do to make it work? Pls. see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952713/parser-error-for-strongly-typed-master-page-in-mvc-2

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when my MVC Master page was outside the 'Views' folder (with my normal Web forms master pages), moving it there solved this error for me.

**Edit**: Sorry I didn't see @Whoiskb already posted the same answer in the comments up there. Just leaving this answer for people who don't read all the comments :)