# ASP.NET MVC - Updating Multiple Partials/View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do you guys update (let's say) two partials in a controller action going to the View?  For example, you have a left nav partial for links and on the right is your main content.  Your main content has a ViewModel that it binds to.  Do you guys have a seperate ViewModel for your nav page?  If so, do you then create a bigger ViewModel each time that has the main content view model and the left nav ViewModel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a strongly typed master page using a base controller in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768236/how-to-create-a-strongly-typed-master-page-using-a-base-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually I was eventually eluding to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768236/how-to-create-a-strongly-typed-master-page-using-a-base-controller-in-asp-net-mvc).  Thanks guys for your input!

Comment: Do not post comments as answer. And accept the one that helped.

Comment: Sorry but they did not lead to the solution.  I thought it would be professional to post the answer that did help.  I'm more concerned with helping people that have the problem then awarding/subtracting points and not posting the solution.

Comment: hi. how is this a solution to the problem? i looked at the solution.

Comment: as in i didn't understand, tho im a vb dev, i can still sort of read c#

Answer (score 0):

I would have one ViewModel for the nav page (e.g. `CategoryListViewModel`) and one for the content page (e.g. `ProductListViewModel`). Then load the `CategoryListViewModel` in a base controller:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    var _categoryRepository = new CategoryRepository();

    protected BaseController()
    {
        ViewData["Categories"] = _categoryRepository.GetCategories();
    }
}

public class ProductsController : BaseController
{
    var _productRepository = new ProductRepository();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_productRepository.GetProducts());
    }
}
```

and then in the `MasterPage` read the categories from the `ViewData`, and in the content page read the products from the `Model` on the `ViewPage`.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the page into different independent sections, have a look at this 
page [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/02/14/asp-net-mvc-rc1-validateinput-a-potential-dangerous-request-and-the-pitfall.aspx). Here you have to use Html.RenderAction() for which you have to
download the ASP.NET MVC Futures assembly from  [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/).