# How can I use and populate a base view model in a master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have an asp.net masterpage, and All my controllers inherit from a controller base. All my view models inherit from ViewBase. How can I have a base set of data in the master page that is populated from the base controller into the viewbase, then into the masterpage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a strongly typed master page using a base controller in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768236/how-to-create-a-strongly-typed-master-page-using-a-base-controller-in-asp-net-mvc) - The dupe is the first related question in the box that appears when you ask one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done in the past is used ViewData to populate my master page.

Inside your master page you can put:

```
<% var baseModel = ViewData["baseModel"] as BaseViewModel; %>
```

then

`baseModel.xx` for whatever properties you need throughout your masterpage.

In my ControllerBase, I then override OnActionExecuting and popluate the viewData with an instance of my baseViewModel.

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        if (filterContext.Canceled || filterContext.Exception != null)
            return;

         var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
         var viewModel = new BaseViewModel();
         PopulateBaseViewModel(viewModel);
         viewResult.ViewData["baseModel"] = viewModel;            
    }
```