# LINQ in a method to use in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor

I am simply trying to retrieve some data from a database, and display it on the _Layouts.cshtml file. And i wanna do this in the with a method in the models folder, right??

My following script down here works, but it's not pretty, take a look.

Here is my model:

```
namespace MvcBreakingNews.Models
{
public class ListCategories
    {
        public IList<string> arrTest() {
            IList<string> myList = new List<string>();
            DataClassesDataContext dt = new DataClassesDataContext();

            var q = from c in dt.categories select c;
            foreach (var item in q)
            {
                myList.Add(item.category1.ToString());
            }
                return myList;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my _Layout.cshtml

```
@using MvcBreakingNews.Models
...

@{
   ListCategories objC = new ListCategories();

   foreach (var item in objC.arrTest())
   {
       <li><a href="#">@item</a></li>         
   }
}
```

Now what i want to do, or what i think i want to do. Is to get rid of the foreach loop in my method and send the array directly to the _Layout.cshtml

How would i do this?

Comment: Do you mean the `foreach` in `arrTest()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ToList()` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx):

```
public IList<string> arrTest()
{
    DataClassesDataContext dt = new DataClassesDataContext();

    var q = from c in dt.categories
            select c.category1.ToString();

    return q.ToList();
}
```

Or you could return `q` directly, which would require changing the return type:

```
public IQueryable<string> arrTest()
{
    DataClassesDataContext dt = new DataClassesDataContext();

    return from c in dt.categories
           select c.category1.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but they did not work for me. Both gave me the same error:
"You cannot implicitly convert type 'blah blah' Are you missing a cast?

But a solution in that direction would be great.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the code you had inside of the `foreach`. See updated answer.

Comment: Cool this works! Thank you very much!
Last question, what do i do if i want to select multiple table cells?

Comment: You mean multiple columns? You can return the whole category object from the `arrTest` method and access that in your cshtml file.

Comment: Ah yes! Columns, sorry.

Hope you don't mind me asking! But how would that look :)?

`
------
        public DataClassesDataContext arrrTest()
        {
            DataClassesDataContext dt = new DataClassesDataContext();
            return dt;
        }

---------layout:-----
ListCategories objC = new ListCategories();
                        var q = from c in objC.arrrTest().categories select c;
-----
`
Witch does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Best way of achieving this is to create a `BaseController` and makes all of your controllers derived from that BaseController.

What your new `BaseController` does is to pass a model for every single time. I hope you got the idea.

Here is a good example :

[How to create a strongly typed master page using a base controller in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768236/how-to-create-a-strongly-typed-master-page-using-a-base-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Auch. Trying to wrap my head around the idea and the example. I think ill go for i simpler solution to begin with, but i will get back to this!
Thanks.

Comment: @user973485 your solution is so fine to get things done quickly but it is not supporting the idea of **Separation of Concerns**. Your views shouldn't care where the data is coming from. It should only care about how to format and output it.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to do the same using Lembda expression is as follows.

```
public IList<string> arrTest()
{
    DataClassesDataContext dt = new DataClassesDataContext();

    return dt.categories.select(c=>c.category1.ToString()).ToList();
}
```